# Is there a good way to store large amounts of similar scraped HTML files in Python?

Tags: python, html, compression, diff

I've written a web scraper in Python and I have a ton (thousands) of files that are extremely similar, but not quite identical. The disk space used currently used by the files is 1.8 GB, but if I compress them into a tar.xz, they compress to 14.4 MB. I want to be closer to that 14.4 MB than the 1.8 GB.

Here are some things I've considered:

I could just use tarfile in Python's standard library and store the files there. The problem with that is I wouldn't be able to modify the files within the tar without recompressing all of the files which would take a while.

I could just use the difflib in Python's standard library, but I've found that this library doesn't offer any way of applying "patches" to recreate the new file.

I could use Google's diff-match-patch Python library, but when I was reading the documentation, they said "Attempting to feed HTML, XML or some other structured content through a fuzzy match or patch may result in problems.", well considering I wanted to use this library to more efficiently store HTML files, that doesn't sound like it'll help me.

So is there a way of saving disk space when storing a large amount of similar HTML files?

Comment: How big are these very similar files?

Comment: Each file is around 30 kb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary.

[Python's zlib interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) supports dictionaries. The `compressobj` and `decompressobj` functions both take an optional *`zdict`* argument, which is a "dictionary". A dictionary in this case is nothing more than 32K of data with sequences of bytes that you expect will appear in the data you are compressing.

Since your files are about 30K each, this works out quite well for your application. If indeed your files are "extremely similar", then you can take one of those files and use it as the dictionary to compress all of the other files.

Try it, and measure the improvement in compression over not using a dictionary.

Comment: So what I'm gathering that you're saying is that if all of the files share, say 95%, of their data, I can use a sort of "template" file that contains that said 95% of shared data, put that into a zdict that can be used to individually compress all of the other files? I would be compressing all of the files individually rather than compressing them as an archive. And I'd have sort of a "key" to decompress the files, so long as that key is less than 32k? Sorry if this is redundant and just restating what you're saying, I'm just making sure I understand this correctly. If so, this sounds perfect.

Comment: I got a little something up and running. It's working out to 1:20 compression ratios or better. Thank you so much!